# It is possible to show the breadcrumb for bootstrap tab navigation

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using bootstrap Tab navigation, and i want to reflect this navigation in a bootstrap breadcrumb. How can I achieve it. This is a similar code i have:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
<li class="active">
    <a data-toggle="tab" href="#">some text</a>
</li>
<li>
    <a data-toggle="tab" href="#">some text1</a>
</li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content">
<div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade in active">
    <!--some content here-->
</div>
<div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane">
    <!--some content here-->
</div>
</div>
```

And I want to add to my page a breadcrumb that shows the navigation to the current active tap for example "Home/some text" if the "some text" tab is the active one. I need a little help to reach this goal.

this is a link to jsfiddle: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/57y0a8hr/)

Comment: We can help you but could you provide a working JSFiddle and the image of you want to achieved?

Comment: you have to use jQuery for achieving this.

Answer (score 0):

It's very basic , but i guess this is the idea you wanted

HTML

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
<li class="active">
    <a class="tab-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#" data-url="#/someUrl1">some text</a>
</li>
<li> 
    <a class="tab-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#" data-url="#/someUrl2">some text1</a>
</li>
</ul>
<ul class="breadcrumb pull-right">
<li> 
    <a href="#">Here</a>
</li>
<li>
    <a href="#/someUrl1" class="active-breadcrumb">some text</a>
</li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content">
<div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade in active">
    <!--some content here-->
</div>
<div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane">
    <!--some content here-->
</div>
</div>
```

JS

```
var activeBreadcrumb = $('.active-breadcrumb');

$('.nav').on('click', '.tab-link', function () {
    var self = $(this);
    activeBreadcrumb.attr('href', self.data('url'));
    activeBreadcrumb.text(self.text());
});
```

Here is working solution
http://jsfiddle.net/mateutek/57y0a8hr/2/

Comment: It looks like you forgot to **Update** the JSFiddle as what it said, _"We're truly sorry, but there is no such page."_

Comment: Yeah sry, didn't notice

Answer (score 0):

Here's my answer, initialize the `.breadcrumb .set-text` element for the existing `.nav-tabs .active`, and change its text according to the text of the clicked `.nav-tabs` link.

```js
var setText = $('.breadcrumb .set-text');

// Initialize .breadcrumb for the existing '.nav-tabs .active'.
setText.addClass('active');
var initText = $('.nav-tabs .active').text();
setText.text(initText);

$('.nav-tabs li a').on('click', function () {
  setText.text($(this).text());
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
<li class="active">
    <a data-toggle="tab" href="#">some text</a>
</li>
<li>
    <a data-toggle="tab" href="#">some text1</a>
</li>
</ul>
<ul class="breadcrumb pull-right">
<li>
    <a href="#">Home</a>
</li>
<li class="set-text">
    <a href="#"></a>
</li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content">
<div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade in active">
    <!--some content here-->
</div>
<div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane">
    <!--some content here-->
</div>
</div>


<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```